# Dynamic Data Structure in C for ordering time_t objects?

Tags: c, data-structures, time, pthreads

I need to add an unknown number of times using pthreads to a data structure and order them earliest first, can anybody recommend a good structure (linked list/ array list) for this?

Comment: Are you looking for recommendations as to what type of data structure or looking for a recommendation of a library to include?

Answer (score 1):

A linked list will be `O(n)` in finding the place where the new object is to go, but constant in inserting it.

A dynamic array/array list will be `O(log(n))` finding the right place but worst case `O(n)` insertion, since you'll need to move all values past the insertion point one over.

If you don't need random access, or at least not until the end, you could use a heap, `O(log(n))` insertion, after you're done you can pull them out in `O(log(n))` each, so `O(n*log(n))` for all of them.

And it's possible there's a (probably tree-based) structure that can do all of it in `O(log(n))` (red-black tree?).

So, in the end it boils down to how, precisely, you want to use it.

Edit: Looked up [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) and it looks like they are `O(log(n))` search ("amortized `O(1)`", according to Wikipedia), insertion, and deletion, so that may be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to order at the end, use a linked-list to store the pthreads maintaining a `count` of records added. Then create an array of size `count` copying the elements to the newly created array and deleting them from the list.
Finally sort the array using qsort.

If you need to maintain an ordered list of pthreads use [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)

The former approach would have the following complexity

```
O(n) for Insert
O(nlog(n)) for Sorting
```

The Later Approach would have

```
O(nlog(n)) for Insert and Fetching
```

You can also see [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)

Please note if you are open in using STL, you can go for [STL priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/priority_queue/)

In terms of memory the later would consume more memory because you have to store two pointers per node.